# sync data in remote machines

Tags: rsync, performance

I am running my calculations on different local machines. Say I have folders AB/ with 95 folders in machine A and corresponding AB/ with 90 folders in machine B. If I run rsync operation, it tries to sync all 95 folders including tons of subfolders within each folders, making it quite inefficient. I want to just copy only 5 folders from machine A to machine B. What's the best way to achieve this goal?

Specifically, when I ran `rsync -rv AB/ $USER@host:/path/to/AB` it tries to match all the folders and subfolders and takes around 4-5 minutes for the whole operation, which is akin to scp the whole folders from A to B.

Comment: Normally, rsync only transfers new or modified parts (delta-transfer) to the target system.

Comment: That's what I thought, but when I ran "rsync -rv AB/ $USER@host:/path/to/AB" it tries to match all the folders and subfolders and takes around 4-5 minutes for the whole operation, which is akin to scp the whole folders from A to B.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `rsync` incorrectly. Without the `-a` flag the program cannot find identical matches on size and timestamp, so it reverts to checksum comparisons.

Try this for copying instead:

```
rsync -av AB/ $USER@host:/path/to/AB
```

Incidentally, if `$USER` is your local account name, just omit it and let `rsync` default to that:

```
rsync -av AB/ host:/path/to/AB
```